# SQL Query same table inner join eliminate duplicate

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table :

```
CREATE TABLE [BGIA].[INTCOL004VA](
[ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[DATYEN] [varchar](18) NULL,
[ZZRIDN] [varchar](8) NULL,
[OQTIEF] [varchar](1) NULL,
[OQMONE] [varchar](3) NULL,
[ZZPONR] [varchar](3) NULL,
[ZZNBRE] [varchar](15) NULL,
[ZZPDSE] [varchar](22) NULL
);

    INSERT INTO INTCOL004VA VALUES
('53671955', 'MC1141103006', '38565363', '1', '007', '010', '0', '0'),
('53671956', 'MC1141103006', '38565363', '0', NULL, '020', '0', '0'),
('53671957', 'MC1141103006', '38565363', '0', '007', '030', '1', '500'),
('53671958', 'VT1141103010', '38565421', '1', '007', '050', '0', '0'),
('53671959', 'VT1141103010', '38565421', '0', NULL, '100', '0', '0'),
('53671960', 'ST1141103006', '38587542', '0', NULL, '010', '1', '500'),
('53671961', 'ST1141103006', '38587542', '1', 'B01', '020', '5', '0');
```

Records are linked by DATYEN, ZZRIDN and ZZPONR

I want update table with this rule :

- For one link DATYEN, ZZRIDN if one row are not 0 on ZZNBRE and ZZPDSE => OQTIEF = 0 and OQMONE = NULL
- But for one link DATYNE, ZZRIDN if all rows ar 0 on ZZNBRE and ZZPDSE and one row have OQTIEF = 1 and OQMONE not null => apply on all row af link OQTIEF = 1 and OQMONE = OQMONE of not null row

I can not do with an INNER JOIN and suddenly I do not know how to succeed

Thank you :)

Edit : For exemple, this :

```
('53671955', 'MC1141103006', '38565363', '1', '007', '010', '0', '0'),
('53671956', 'MC1141103006', '38565363', '0', NULL, '020', '0', '0'),
('53671957', 'MC1141103006', '38565363', '0', '007', '030', '1', '500')
```

Must be :

```
('53671955', 'MC1141103006', '38565363', '0', NULL, '010', '0', '0'),
('53671956', 'MC1141103006', '38565363', '0', NULL, '020', '0', '0'),
('53671957', 'MC1141103006', '38565363', '0', NULL, '030', '1', '500')
```

Because group MC1141103006 and 38565363 have one row with ZZNBRE and ZZPDSE not 0

This :

```
('53671960', 'ST1141103006', '38587542', '0', NULL, '010', '1', '500'),
('53671961', 'ST1141103006', '38587542', '1', 'B01', '020', '5', '0')
```

Must be :

```
('53671960', 'ST1141103006', '38587542', '0', NULL, '010', '1', '500'),
('53671961', 'ST1141103006', '38587542', '0', NULL, '020', '0', '0')
```

Because group ST1141103006 and 38587542 have one row with ZZNBRE and ZZPDSE not 0 but set ZZNBRE to 0 because ZZPDSE is 0

And this :

```
('53671958', 'VT1141103010', '38565421', '1', '007', '050', '0', '0'),
('53671959', 'VT1141103010', '38565421', '0', NULL, '100', '0', '0')
```

Must be :

```
('53671958', 'VT1141103010', '38565421', '1', '007', '050', '0', '0'),
('53671959', 'VT1141103010', '38565421', '1', '007', '100', '0', '0')
```

Because all row have ZZNBRE and ZZNBRE are 0

I hope to be precise, it is not easy to understand I guess :(

Edit 2 : Actually my query is :

```
update v1
set v1.zznbre = (case when v1.zzpdse = 0 then 0 else v1.zznbre end),
v1.oqtief = (case when v1.zznbre = 0 and v2.zznbre = 0 and v1.zzpdse = 0 and v2.zzpdse = 0 then 1 else 0 end),
v1.oqmone = (case when v1.zznbre = 0 and v2.zznbre = 0 and v1.zzpdse = 0 and v2.zzpdse = 0 then v2.oqmone else null end)
from intcol004va v1
inner join intcol004va v2 on v2.datyen = v1.datyen and v2.zzridn = v1.zzridn and v2.id <> v1.id
where v2.oqtief = 1 and v2.oqmone is not null and v1.oqtief <> v2.oqtief
```

But not work correctly in all case :(

Comment: Can u explain the update rule bit more. It is not clear

Comment: Can you please use normal names?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  We're happy to see you :)  Posting your full table structure like that is a great help, and we appreciate that.  As others have pointed out, though, your question is a little hard to understand.  Can you show us any SQL or sample data that would make your rule a little clearer?  Maybe set up a SQL Fiddle example so that we can see what you are talking about?

Comment: I added some details

Comment: Why can't you do inner joins? You can do inner joins with UPDATE if you use aliases. Is that your problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you process the update as two independent updates it appears to generate the correct answer set.
I included a result table and code that will show a comparison between original data and the desired result table as defined from your description.

Next it will do the two updates and then show the joined original and goal tables to demonstrate that they are aligned correctly.

```
CREATE TABLE [INTCOL004VA](
[ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[DATYEN] [varchar](18) NULL,
[ZZRIDN] [varchar](8) NULL,
[OQTIEF] [varchar](1) NULL,
[OQMONE] [varchar](3) NULL,
[ZZPONR] [varchar](3) NULL,
[ZZNBRE] [varchar](15) NULL,
[ZZPDSE] [varchar](22) NULL
);

CREATE TABLE [R_INTCOL004VA](
[ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[DATYEN] [varchar](18) NULL,
[ZZRIDN] [varchar](8) NULL,
[OQTIEF] [varchar](1) NULL,
[OQMONE] [varchar](3) NULL,
[ZZPONR] [varchar](3) NULL,
[ZZNBRE] [varchar](15) NULL,
[ZZPDSE] [varchar](22) NULL
);

INSERT INTO INTCOL004VA VALUES
('53671955', 'MC1141103006', '38565363', '1', '007', '010', '0', '0'),
('53671956', 'MC1141103006', '38565363', '0', NULL, '020', '0', '0'),
('53671957', 'MC1141103006', '38565363', '0', '007', '030', '1', '500'),
('53671958', 'VT1141103010', '38565421', '1', '007', '050', '0', '0'),
('53671959', 'VT1141103010', '38565421', '0', NULL, '100', '0', '0'),
('53671960', 'ST1141103006', '38587542', '0', NULL, '010', '1', '500'),
('53671961', 'ST1141103006', '38587542', '1', 'B01', '020', '5', '0');

INSERT INTO [R_INTCOL004VA] VALUES
('53671955', 'MC1141103006', '38565363', '0', NULL, '010', '0', '0'),
('53671956', 'MC1141103006', '38565363', '0', NULL, '020', '0', '0'),
('53671957', 'MC1141103006', '38565363', '0', NULL, '030', '1', '500'),
('53671960', 'ST1141103006', '38587542', '0', NULL, '010', '1', '500'),
('53671961', 'ST1141103006', '38587542', '0', NULL, '020', '0', '0'),
('53671958', 'VT1141103010', '38565421', '1', '007', '050', '0', '0'),
('53671959', 'VT1141103010', '38565421', '1', '007', '100', '0', '0')


SELECT
    D.ID, 
    D.DATYEN, 
    D.ZZRIDN, 
    D.OQTIEF, 
    E.OQTIEF AS CORRECT_OQTIEF, 
    D.OQMONE, 
    E.OQMONE AS CORRECT_OQMONE, 
    D.ZZPONR, 
    D.ZZNBRE, 
    D.ZZPDSE
FROM
    INTCOL004VA AS D 
INNER JOIN
    R_INTCOL004VA AS E ON D.ID = E.ID

UPDATE 
    INTCOL004VA
SET
    OQTIEF = 0,
    OQMONE = NULL
FROM 
    INTCOL004VA AS A 
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        B.DATYEN,
        B.ZZRIDN
    FROM
        INTCOL004VA AS B
    GROUP BY
        B.DATYEN,
        B.ZZRIDN
    HAVING
        SUM(CAST(B.ZZNBRE AS INT)) > 0
    ) AS C ON A.DATYEN = C.DATYEN AND A.ZZRIDN = C.ZZRIDN


UPDATE 
    INTCOL004VA
SET
    OQTIEF = 1,
    OQMONE = C.OQMONE
FROM 
    INTCOL004VA AS A 
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        B.DATYEN,
        B.ZZRIDN,
        MAX(ISNULL(B.OQMONE,'')) AS OQMONE
    FROM
        INTCOL004VA AS B
    GROUP BY
        B.DATYEN,
        B.ZZRIDN
    HAVING
        SUM(CAST(B.OQTIEF AS INT)) > 0
    ) AS C ON A.DATYEN = C.DATYEN AND A.ZZRIDN = C.ZZRIDN   


SELECT
    D.ID, 
    D.DATYEN, 
    D.ZZRIDN, 
    D.OQTIEF, 
    E.OQTIEF AS CORRECT_OQTIEF, 
    D.OQMONE, 
    E.OQMONE AS CORRECT_OQMONE, 
    D.ZZPONR, 
    D.ZZNBRE, 
    D.ZZPDSE
FROM
    INTCOL004VA AS D 
INNER JOIN
    R_INTCOL004VA AS E ON D.ID = E.ID
```

Sometimes just breaking it up into smaller pieces is the easier way to attack the problem.

Comment: Impossible in one query ? :(

Comment: I am sure it can be done in one action, but the issue then become complexity and readability.  Not just for yourself, but for the next developer who has to maintain this script after you.  A battle I have at work is always between these two forces and often we will side for a slightly slower code that is easier to maintain and easier to validate.  Accuracy is more important than shaving and extra 3ms. With that being said I do enjoy being able to write an uber complex query just because it was a challenge and I thought I could do it, but my jr. developers hate me when I do it.

Comment: @BenjaminCEREDE you always can wrap all in one transaction